# Unable to load class 'groovy.lang.GroovyObject'

Tags: android-studio, gradle, groovy, build

since I upgraded to android studio 3.0.1 I can not continue with my application. Gradle throws the following error: Gradle Sync Issues

> **Error: Unable to load class 'groovy.lang.GroovyObject'.** Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> Gradle's
>   dependency cache may be corrupt (this happens after a network
>   connection timeout.)  Re-download dependencies
>   and sync project (requires network)
>
> The state of a
>   Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle
>   daemons may solve this problem.  Stop
>   Gradle build processes (requires restart)
>
> Your
>   project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with
>   the other plugins in the project or the Grade requested by the
>   project.   In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you
>   can also try to close the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

**If you made an update to Android 3.0+ do not forget to perform the cache invalidation in Android Studio and restart.**

`File` > `Invalidate Cache / Restart`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing the compilation by command line, through the terminal that has integrated Android Studio:

```
./gradlew clean assemble
```

Comment: Thanks, @EstebanCastiblancoMoncaleano, i solved the problem in this way:https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/119607/error-al-refrescar-proyecto-con-gradle/119626#119626

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the following line in project's `grandle.wrapper.properties` file:

From:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4.1-all.zip
```

After that i could successfully build my project again.

Not sure why it was not working with version 4.1 since both versions exists in `%HOMEPATH%\.gradle\wrapper\dists` folder.